# How to pass string parameter to nested function, which has already parameters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is how my Categories react functional component looks like. For easier testing, I split up the handleClick and the react component itself - but that shouldn't be an issue for this question.

How do I pass the component string value from the `map()` to the `handleClick()`? `handleClick` already passes some operator parameter, which gets me struggling with this simple issue...

```
export const useCategories = () => {
  const handleClick = (operator) => {
    updateCategory({
      variables: {
        id: '123',
        operator,
        category // <-- this value is missing
      }
    })
  }

  return {
    icon: {
      onClick: handleClick('$pull') // <-- Here I add some operator value
    }
  }
}

export const Categories = () => {
  const { icon } = useCategories()

  return (
      <div>
        {categories.map((category) => <Icon onClick={icon.onClick} />)} {/* <-- how to pass category value to handleClick...? */}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to "add" a variable, you can use [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).
Hence, return a function that receives the new argument and use it internally:

```
export const useCategories = () => {
  return (category) => {
    const handleClick = (operator) => {
      updateCategory({
        variables: {
          id: '123',
          operator,
          category // now this is the argument of the wrapper function
        }
      })
    };

    return () => handleClick('$pull');
  };
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
export const Categories = () => {
  const getOnClick = useCategories();

  return (
      <div>
        {categories.map((category) => {
          const onClick = getOnClick(category);
          return <Icon onClick={onClick} />;
        })}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I don't see where/how you add `category`... `useCategory` is called before the `map()` loop. But there the category value is accessable...

Comment: I added the rest of the code @user3142695

Comment: My code is a very simplified version of what I'm using. So there are multiple functions, that's why I'm returning an object with all functions (here `icon.onClick`). This object is used in the component. Is it still possible to do it like you explained?

Comment: Of course. You can adjust the return value of the function that's returned from `useCategories`

Comment: Couldn't I pass the param like `{ icon: { onClick: (category) => handleClick('$pull', category) }}` and `const handleClick = (operator, category) => {}`? If yes, what is the difference?